# Sensei's Divining Top activations

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-competitive-rel

A player in a competitive REL tournament pays 1 mana to activate [Sensei's Divining Top](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSensei%27s%5d%2b%5bDivining%5d%2b%5bTop%5d)'s ability to look at the top 3 cards of his library, looks at the 3 cards, changes the order and put them back.

**Without performing any further actions or saying/implying that the spell is resolved, can that player then return to look at those 3 cards again?**

Comment: this is a question that I have had come up while testing decks, but never actually in a tournament. interested to know the answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No** they can not look at the cards again.

> 1 : Look at the top three cards of your library, then put them back in
>   any order.

By placing the cards back on the library they have finished taking all the actions the  ability allowed and then it finishes resolving.

If you were playing a very competitive game, this is not a legal thing to do.

I do not think there is any way to interpret the above rule and all its parts to allow a player to re-do the last step of an ability.

Furthermore the rules do not have anything in them about a player stating that anything resolves. A spell resolves when all of the steps listed in its text have been completed.

> 608.2c The controller of the spell or ability follows its instructions in the order written...

Comment: could you please post  the text of rule 608, or at least a link to the source?

Comment: its in the comprehensive rules and it spans 11 sub sections. I only put it in there because it is the appropriate rule concerning resolving a spell. I could post the whole body of the rule if you really think it would help, but the importance of that rule in this situation is what is not defined there. [this is the wizards of the coast page for the rules](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/TCG/Article.aspx?x=magic/rules) the comprehensive can be found there.

Comment: [you mean here?](http://media.wizards.com/images/magic/tcg/resources/rules/MagicCompRules_20130201.pdf)

Comment: well I would mean there except that is going to link to the rules that are current today. The link I provided will bring a user to the page where the rules can be found and then they can click the link which will lead them to the rules that are most current in the future. :)

Comment: Hmm, I think you could probably trim that down to the pertinent sub-rules without losing the value. 608.2c is really the only interesting one in this case.

Comment: That is what I felt also but it is reallt only the first sentence in 608.2c